# populating table or range to listbox in userform to get the values of the columns inside the table or range in closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The problem is that the code is not working with me and gives "type mismatch error"

```
   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

     Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = _
                     "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                     "Data Source=F:\Book1.xlsx;" & _
                     "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
    
    
      
    cn.Open
     Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn

    rs.Source = "select [date] ,[factory] ,[records] from [sheet1$]"
    
    rs.Open
     With Me.ListBox1
     .ColumnCount = rs.RecordCount
     .List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
      
     End With

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) You get your type mismatch error because `rs.RecordCount` is of type `LongLong` which VBA cannot implicitly convert into a `long`. You could convert is explicitly with `CLng(rs.RecordCount)`

(2) When using Excel as data source, RecordCount will always be `-1` as the Excel engine doesn't support RecordCount (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordcount-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver16).

(3) You probably don't want to have `RecordCount` as number of *columns* for your listview anyhow - I assume you want to get the number of fields as column count:

```
With Me.ListBox1
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = rs.Fields.Count
    .List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
End With
```